# Get cell data using XPath expression

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to fetch a table cell value using importxml() in Google Sheets. The function I'm using to get Forward P/E value is: =IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RELIANCE.NS/key-statistics?p=RELIANCE.NS",
"/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STQTL.png)/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STQTL.png)/div/div[3]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STQTL.png)/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STQTL.png)/div/div/section/div[2]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STQTL.png)/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")

I have taken the Xpath using Google Dev (Inspect). I want to get the value **24.81** highlighted in the image.
[image: Yahoo Finance - Reliance]

Please help me in identifying what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't retrieve informations using native google function and xpath since this site is build in your side by javascript.

But you can parse a big json contained in the source.

Try

```
function yahoo(){
  var url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RELIANCE.NS/key-statistics?p=RELIANCE.NS&guccounter=1'
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  console.log(data.context.dispatcher.stores.QuoteTimeSeriesStore.timeSeries.trailingForwardPeRatio[0].reportedValue.fmt)
}
```